# What files do I need to update after moving magento from "127.0.0.1" on one PC to another running on "localhost"

Tags: installation

My friend and I are developing a magento theme together. His Magento installation was **running on 127.0.0.1** and **mine on localhost**. After we've moved the files from his to mines the theme only renders the partially the header and no new CSS, or javascript seems to be rendered on my laptop.

I'm guessing the problem is because his server was different from mines being "127.0.0.1" and mines being "localhost" therefore the images, css, and javascript won't load on my PC.

**What files do I need to update to fix this?**

Comment: You can't run Magento at http://localhost/ due to well-documented requirements that it needs a TLD; most developers use localhost.dev or something to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update this in the database. Run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE value LIKE '%localhost%';
```

And replace all instances with your `127.0.0.1`.

**A few other thoughts:**

- You can update this fairly easily with [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun)
- You should be using a TLD or a "." somewhere in your domain even on dev; most of our developers choose localhost.dev or something similar

Answer (score 0):

you have to change in two places

1) open your mysql in find the core_config_data and change the two fields as below Image.

[image]

2) Second change will be app/etc/local.xml  find the below code.

```
       <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[magento18]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
```

and change the username and password and after that remove your cache form your var/cache folder and run your website.

Comment: The section in local.xml has nothing to do with website base urls

Comment: yes nothing to do it will automatically take new url for whole site

Answer (score 0):

for installation t start again just delete `app/etc/local.xml` file and access your project from browser. now your installation process will be triggered again.

Answer (score -1):

app/etc/local.xml
also check your mysql

Comment: What should they look for in local.xml and in mysql.